# How to set Hightcharts column chart with distuibuted bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Now i have know how to get charts like this: 
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange
The official demo shows how to set one data area of a column,
the problem is how to set a distributed data set of each data-set,like this[distributed data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQDpy.png)

Comment: See [Gantt](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart) series type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide the appropriate values in the data.

The `columnrange` series type takes three values: `[x,low,high]`.

Provide the same x value, and the various y values, and the chart does what you want by default

```
data: [
  [0,1,3],
  [0,5,8],
  [0,10,15],
  [1,2,6],
  ...
  ...
]
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/4ry5vLc4/

Comment: Thanks a lot , that saves my time!